# SPA Durandal app: how can i reload current page in router

Tags: jquery, html, durandal, navbar, router

I have SPA application, in which the shell contains link tags for the menu.
all link in the menu has href="#pagenme", and it works fine.

my problem is, that when i click again in the menu the page that is show - it isn't reloaded, nothing happens.
i ave seen this also in the Durandal starter example: when clicking flicker, the page is shown. clicking again flicker - nothing happens, and i wish the page will be loaded.

somebody has a solution for me?

also i dont want to navigate to page - cause i dont to change the url syntax.

thanks

Comment: I'm curious. Why would you want the page to reload? Durandal caches your views by default. Does it change in-between viewings (i.e. it's not the same from one click to the next)?

Comment: try `window.location.reload(true);` in click event. Just check if current page URL and menu URL are same, then call this code else do not do anything. Let me know if you need any other help.

Answer (score 0):

The route that is currently active can be refreshed using the following line of code:

```
 router.activeItem().activate();
```